Connecting edges of two line features while retaining their attributes of both in QGIS
I want to connect the bottom-right edges of the two line features shown in the map. I want to achieve two line features connected while keeping their attributes.
Could anyone guide me on how to accomplish this?


Can you provide more information what you tried so far and how you want to connect those lines (shortest distance, extension of both lines, ...)?

I want to extend both lines and then connect them.

Perhaps this video on youtube helps.

You can use the tool "Extend lines" on the layer/both layers (depending on your project structure). Chose an extension length for the beginning/end (depending on the direction of your features), so an overlap of the exenstions is guaranteed. All data from your original layer is stored in the new layer as well. Now you can edit the vertex of the respective features in combination with the snapping toolbar (enable "Enable snapping on intersection") to move the vertices to the intersection where both lines meet.
